# Trigger to update table according to user rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm a stranger to SQL Server Triggers.
I ended up having a problem like this. Please have a look.

1. I have two tables 'users' & 'test'

   ```
      CREATE TABLE users( 
                email VARCHAR(250),
                rank FLOAT
         );

       CREATE TABLE test(
             score INT,
            total INT
       );
   ```
2. I need to create a trigger to;

   2.1 Update users rank by the value of avg **( avg = test.score / test.total)**
     2.2 Here's What I tried so far:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER auto_rank ON dbo.test FOR INSERT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sc INT
    DECLARE @tot INT
    DECLARE @avg FLOAT
    @tot = SELECT inserted.total FROM dbo.test
    @sc = SELECT inserted.score FROM dbo.test
    SET @avg=@sc/@tot
    UPDATE dbo.users SET rank=@avg WHERE email=inserted.email
    END
   ```

Comment: Do you have `email` field in `test` table ? And also tell what problem are you facing ?

Comment: `inserted` is a pseudo-table and can contain *multiple* rows. Assigning a column value from it to a scalar variable is thus *always* a mistake.

Comment: Also, `SET @avg=@sc/@tot` will perform the division in `int`s, *before* converting to `float` and assigning to `@avg`. It's thus likely that this will be 0.

Comment: @RaviSingh Thank You ravi. Yes I had those extra attributes but I reduced them in order to prevent high complexity to u all. THe problem is that I get errors Err[42000] all over the place with the trigger i've written

Comment: @Damien_THe_Unbeliever Thank U Damien, Can u please post a proper trigger that will worth a million right now. I'm less accustomed to these concepts still.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for being so late to continue this thread but, I'm happy to say that I found the answer. it's because of you all.

So, here's what i did;

first;

```
CREATE TABLE users( 
   email VARCHAR(250),
   rank FLOAT,
   constraint pk_users PRIMARY KEY(email)
);

CREATE TABLE test(
   email VARCHAR(250),
   score INT,
   total INT,
   constraint pk_test PRIMARY KEY(email),
   constraint fk_from_users FOREIGN KEY(email) references users(email)
);

create trigger trig_ex02 on dbo.test
after insert
as
begin
declare @score FLOAT
declare @total FLOAT
declare @average FLOAT
declare @msg varchar(100)
declare @email varchar(250)
set @email = (select email from inserted)
set @score = (select score from inserted)
set @total = (select total from inserted)
set @average =(@score/@total)
select @msg = 'SCORE IS'+ str(@score)+'TOTAL IS'+str(@total)+' AVERAGE IS ' +str(@average,25,5)+' END '
print @msg
UPDATE users SET rank=@average WHERE users.email=@email
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing the email in test from your table design, but it should have such column per your code:

```
UPDATE dbo.users SET rank=@avg WHERE email=inserted.email
```

Then you need a view instead of trigger in this case:

```
Create view user as (select email, score/total as rank from test group by email);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: @setevens wu Many thanks to u for the reply. Thank U. but , I need to have a trigger. according to database design & system demands it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your tables so that the test table contains the email column:

```
CREATE TABLE test(score INT,
                  total INT,
                  email varchar(250)
                 );
```

Then you can create the trgiger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[auto_rank] ON [dbo].[test]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
  DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT score, total, email FROM Inserted
  DECLARE @sc INT
  DECLARE @tot INT
  DECLARE @email VARCHAR(30)
  DECLARE @avg FLOAT
  DECLARE @MSG VARCHAR(50)
  OPEN MyCursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @sc, @tot, @email
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SELECT @avg=@sc/@tot
    UPDATE users SET rank=@avg WHERE users.email=@email
    SELECT @MSG = 'email Updated ' + @email + '. New Rank is ' + Str(@avg, 25, 5);
    PRINT @MSG
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
  END;
  CLOSE MyCursor;
  DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
END
```

Comment: `inserted` is a pseudo-table and can contain *multiple* rows. Assigning a column value from it to a scalar variable is thus *always* a mistake.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ur right thank you, i will fix the answer

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for making this understandable for me.

Comment: @TwoMore Many thanks for you You've done so much work. Thank You again

Comment: @TwoMore The trigger worked thanks to you but the output is blank & also the users table doesn't update as it's supposed to be. Can you plz help.

Comment: @HarinLakmal which output is blank? creating trigger has no output, and which data do you have in the users table? if you enter test data to users which doesnt have any email this aint gona work, you refer the user by his email address, please post the output and input data if you face problems in a separate question.

Comment: @TwoMore Sorry for being late 2 reply. But, there's a print function isn't it? it produces an output result

Comment: @HarinLakmal How about you set a breakpoint and debug into it to see what happends?

Comment: @TwoMore I found the answer many thanks to your answer, it was helpful a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_rank ON dbo.test FOR INSERT
BEGIN



UPDATE a SET a.rank=b.rn

from 
users a
inner join
(select email,inserted.score/inserted.total rn from inserted)b 
on a.email=b.email

END
```

I have not tested this, but this should work fine.

Comment: @Harin Lakmal : Did this help ?